# Chromatic polynomial of a $8$-vertex graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

I'm supposed to determine chromatic polynomial of a $8$-vertex graph, which is the result of sticking

There are two complete $5$-vertex graphs, each with one edge removed, in the first graph we remove the edge $uv$ and in the second graph we remove $u'v'$. Then we stick the graphs together by putting $u=u'$ and $v=v'$ . I hope the description is quite clear, because I don't know how to insert the image of this graph.

It seems pointless to try using the recurrence formula for chromatic polynomial of a graph (by trying to get complete graphs by contracting together two unconnected vertices and drawing an additional edge linking them).

Could you help me with that?

Comment: If we take two copies of $K_5$ and merge two vertices in one copy with two vertices in the other, the resulting graph has only eight vertices.

Comment: Oh, right, it is an 8-vertice graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to see this from first principles: remember that $P(x)$ is the number of colourings of the graph using $x$ colours.

If you fix the colours of the two vertices in the middle (which used to be $u$ and $v$), then the remaining graph splits into two separate complete graphs which are very simple to count colourings in.

(At this point you should ask yourself: if there are $3$ ways to colour each copy, how many different ways are there to colour both together?  Hint: it's not $6$.)

The exact number of colourings of each complete graph (as a function of $x$) depends on whether you colour $u$ and $v$ the same colour or distinct colours, so consider these two cases separately, and remember to account for how many ways there are to choose the two initial colours.

Comment: Well, if we consider a graph with 5 vertices where $u$ and $v$ are not connected then for such a graph if $u$ and $v$ have different colours we get x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4) possible colourings and if $u$ and $v$ have the same colours we get x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3) possible colourings. Now, the answer in my textbook is $\frac{(x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4))^2}{x(x-1)} + \frac{(x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3))^2}{x}$. Could you tell me what to do next? Or did I just understand you incorrectly?

Comment: @Hagrid You're on the right track but you need to take into account that your graph contains *two* such graphs of 5 vertices.  There are $x(x-1)$ ways to choose $u$ and $v$ with different colours, and $x$ ways to choose them with the same colour.  How many choices for the remaining 6 vertices?  It helps if you have given some thought about where formulas like $x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ come from.

Comment: From the picture that @Robert Israel presented below we can see that if $u, \ v$ have the same colour, then we choose colour of the base and then of the vertices of three triangles in x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3) ways and if their colours are different we do it in x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4) ways. Is that correct?

Comment: @Hagrid Let's make this more concrete by picking, say $x=6$.  There are $6\cdot 5 = 30$ ways to colour $u$ and $v$ differently.  Now there are $4$ colours remaining, since we cannot reuse $u$ and $v$'s colours: how many ways can you colour all *six* remaining vertices?  (Certainly there is more freedom in colouring two triangles than just one of them.)

Comment: Having coloured the two middle vertices (1 and 2), we can the colour the "3" in 4 ways, "4" in 3 ways and "5" in 2 ways. Since We can repeat it for "3'", "4'", "5'" because they are not directly linked to "3", "4", "5".

Comment: Ok, I think I see that now. First we count the possibilities of colouring the two middle vertices and then the "side" ones and since they are not connected (I mean that the vertices on the right side of u,v are not connected to those on the left side of u,v) then we can just count the possibilities of colouring the left ones and since there is the same number of vertices on the left as there is on the right, we just square it. Is that correct? I hope it's comprehensible.

Comment: @Hagrid Sounds good to me, yup (sounded good as soon as you mentioned squaring the number of colourings on one side).

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help, and patience :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is your graph.  Shown is a 4-colouring.  It's easy to see there are $4$-cliques, so the chromatic number is $4$.

[image]

EDIT:
I suggest you look at two separate cases, where $1$ and $2$ have the same colour
and where they have different colours.  Note that given the colours of vertices
$1$ and $2$, vertices $3$, $4$ and $5$ can have any three different colours that are 
not those of $1$ and $2$, and similarly for $3'$, $4'$ and $5'$.

Comment: But the question asks for the chromatic polynomial, not the chromatic number.

Comment: Yes, but see the last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

So, here's the graph:

[image: The OP's graph]

and another method for finding the chromatic polynomial.

We can use the addition/identification law on the vertices $x$ and $y$ to compute the chromatic polynomial.  The law states that if $x$ and $y$ are not adjacent, then the $$P(G,\lambda)=P(G+xy,\lambda)+P(G/xy,\lambda).$$

In this case, the chromatic polynomial of the above graph is the sum of the chromatic polynomials of the graphs:

[image: Addition of edge <span class=]$xy$">

and

[image: Identification of <span class=]$x$ and $y$">

These graphs are clique separable copies of complete graphs.  Thus, they have the chromatic polynomials $$\frac{P(K_5;\lambda)^2}{P(K_2;\lambda)}$$ and $$\frac{P(K_4;\lambda)^2}{P(K_1;\lambda)},$$ respectively.

The chromatic polynomial of the complete graph $K_n$ is $$P(K_n;\lambda)=\lambda(\lambda-1)\cdots(\lambda-n+1).$$

Hence the chromatic polynomial of the original graph is: $$\frac{\big(\lambda(\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)(\lambda-3)(\lambda-4)\big)^2}{\lambda(\lambda-1)}+\frac{\big(\lambda(\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)(\lambda-3)\big)^2}{\lambda}$$ which simplifies to $$\lambda(\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)^2(\lambda-3)^2(\lambda^2-7\lambda+15).$$

Answer (score 0):

Use Mathematica to calculate the answer

```
g1 = CompleteGraph[5] // VertexAdd[#, {6, 7, 8}] &
g2 = CompleteGraph[5] // IndexGraph[#, 4] &

yourGraph=BooleanGraph[Xor, g1, g2, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
chroPoly=ChromaticPolynomial[yourGraph, k]
```

$$
k^8-18 k^7+139 k^6-591 k^5+1480 k^4-2163 k^3+1692 k^2-540 k
$$

```
chroPoly//Factor
```

$$
(k-3)^2 (k-2)^2 (k-1) k \left(k^2-7 k+15\right)
$$

```
Table[chroPoly, {k, 1, 10}]
```

$$
\{0,0,0,144,3600,38880,252000,1159200,4191264,12700800\}
$$