# planar graph and its complement

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

> Prove that there is no 9-vertex planar graph $G$, such that the chromatic polynomial of $G$ is equal to the chromatic polynomial of $\overline{G}$. >
>
> The chromatic polynomial of graphs is defined [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial).

I thought that maybe we can use *Kuratowski's theorem*, but I do not know how.
Actually, because this theorem gives a straightforward condition for a graph to be planar, I tried to use contradiction and the use this theorem, but I got confused.

Note: The graph should not necessarily be connected.

Comment: What made you think you can use a certain theorem? Please elaborate so the community members can guide you.  We encourage you to show your work & effort. 

Comment: Actually Because this theorem gives a straightforward condition for a graph to be planar, I tried to use contradiction and the use this theorem, but I got confused.

Comment: Great! Can you please, copy your comment and paste it into the post? Not many users read comments.  I haven't encountered graph theory so far, but I found a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2858693/721644) regarding _Kuratowski's theorem_. Maybe you could find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2749307/721644) useful, too.

Comment: @Cheesecake sure

Comment: You might also see [Chromatic Polynomial of a Planar Graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/683233/721644). Have you seen [Chromatic Polynomial of a $8$-vertex Graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/289984/721644)?

Comment: See this answer by [@Idéophage](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2379476/721644) and also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1052591/721644).

Comment: Could you write some of your work and clarify where exactly the step you got confused about?

Answer (score 7):

You'll have some difficulty, because such a graph does exist. The planar graph below and its complement both have chromatic polynomial $$x^9-18 x^8+141 x^7-627 x^6+1728 x^5-3015 x^4+3242 x^3-1956 x^2+504 x.$$

[image]

Found by downloading the $71885$ connected planar graphs [from here](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html), and checking the $18$-edge ones for the chromatic polynomial condition using Mathematica. There are a total of $19$ examples.

If anyone wants to check my work, the graph6 code for this graph is `>>graph6<<H?C^L\v`. For example, the following Mathematica code will do:

```
graph = ImportString[">>graph6<<H?C^L\\v"]
PlanarGraphQ[graph]
ChromaticPolynomial[graph, x]
ChromaticPolynomial[GraphComplement[graph], x]
```

---

However, there are no possible examples with *more* than $9$ vertices. The reason is that the chromatic polynomial of a $n$-edge, $m$-vertex graph begins with $x^n - m x^{n-1}$, followed by lower-order terms. So if $G$ and $\overline{G}$ have the same chromatic polynomial, they both have the same number of edges: $\frac12 \binom n2$.

For $n=10$, this requires having $22.5$ edges, which is impossible. For $n \ge 11$, the required number of edges exceeds $3n-6$: the most edges that a planar graph can have.

Comment: Wow, looks nice. Is there anyway to check this mathematically?

Comment: Are there simple examples between those 18 examples?

Comment: None of the ones I looked at seemed particularly nice. Of course with sufficient patience, you could compute the chromatic polynomial of this graph, and its complement, by hand - but using a computer is easier.

Comment: On the other hand, for 8 vertices, there is a nice solution: all ten self-complementary graphs on 8 vertices are planar.

Comment: Yes, I have seen lots of good examples for 8 vertices too.

Comment: actually because the expantion for the above polynomial is $(x−3)2(x−2)3(x−1)x(x2−5x+7)$, I this is not possible to calculate it because it has real roots.

Comment: Another thing I have to mention is that the graph should not necessarily be connected!

Comment: The graph doesn't need to be connected, but there wasn't a database of disconnected planar graphs, I would have to do more coding. I figured that I found 19 examples this way and it was good enough! The disconnected examples would also have to be very constrained: essentially, the $18$-edge, $8$-vertex planar graphs, together with an isolated vertex.